# ruby/rails how to ignore a comma in when ordering

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a price field for a product in a catalog.  Sometimes the admin user is putting a comma when dealing with thousands (ex: $10,000) and sometimes he is just doing $6000.  While I would like to simply tell him to do it one way or the other, I would also like to solve the issue programmatically.

The #show action responsible is here:

```
def show
       @category = Category.find_by_url_name(params[:category_id])
       @brand = Brand.find(params[:id])

       @search = Product.find(:all, :conditions => ['brand_id = ? and  category_id = ?', @brand.id, @category.id],
          :order=> params[:order] || 'price DESC')
       @products = @search.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 12 )

    @meta_title = "#{@brand.name}"
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @brand }
    end
  end
```

I also have a sort_options helper in my application helper that is providing the ordering options to the site user:

```
def product_sort_options
    options_for_select([
      ['', nil],
      ['Newest to Oldest', 'descend_by_date'],
      ['Oldest to Newest', 'ascend_by_date'],
      ['Price: Highest to Lowest', 'descend_by_price'],
      ['Price: Lowest to Highest', 'ascend_by_price'],
      ['Name', 'ascend_by_name']
    ])
  end
```

any ideas?

Comment: Why is your price a string, in the first place?!? Keep it as decimal, and decorate with `$` and `,` at display time. Strip them at input time.

Comment: I probably should have but, it was early on in my working with rails... Didn't know any better, now there are 300 products... so changing them out would suck

Comment: It shouldn't. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it a full answer - `price` should not be a string. The fact that you have 300 products now is not a big deal.

Make a migration:

```
rails generate migration decimalise
```

Then edit it (`db/migrate/*decimalise.rb`), and write something like this:

```
class Decimalise < ActiveRecord::Migration                                                                                                                                                                                       
  def up
    connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection()
    # kill the weird chars in the string field
    connection.execute("UPDATE products SET price = REPLACE(REPLACE(price, ',', ''), '$', '')")

    # convert the string column into a decimal one
    change_table :products do |t|
      # adjust for your use case - this gives you values up to 9999999.99
      # if you need more, increase the 10
      t.column :price, :decimal, :precision => 10, :scale => 2
    end
  end

  def down
    change_table :products do |t|
      t.column :price, :string, :limit => 10
    end
  end
end
```

then finally, run

```
rake db:migrate
```

(untested, you will probably need to tweak. also, back up your DB before any tinkering - I'll not be responsible for any data loss you suffer)

**EDIT** One thing I forgot: how to print it out.

```
<%= number_to_currency @product.price %>
```

should give you something like `$1,999.99` for a price of `1999.99`.

Comment: Wow ok this makes a lot of sense... So I am no mysql wiz but it looks like you are doing a gsub then converting to decimal

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Thanks for the info.  I had to modify slightly because I am still running Rails 2.3.x but I got it and appreciate the  help

Answer (score 1):

You can use [String.gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) to search the commas and replace them by nothing.

Comment: If you wanted to get rid of everything except the digits, you could also: your_value_string.scan(/\d/).join('')